# Sublime Text 2/3 shortcut to show/hide/toggle tabs

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'm searching for a way to toggle tab visibility in Sublime Text 2 or 3.
I've seen the 'hide tabs' plugin, but it doesn't fit my needs, and neither does [this script](https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1357) (the API seems to have changed since 2010).

I just want to bind a keyboard shortcut to toggle tab visibility.

Comment: About time you switched to ST3? :-) All the big plug-ins (Anaconda, SublimeLinter...) have already migrated.

Comment: yes I should, but i'm a bit lazy... I know it will take me some time to migrate all my stuff...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Open the console <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and type:

```
sublime.log_commands(True)
```

Then click View -> Toggle tabs yourself and observe the console:

```
command: toggle_tabs
```

You've got the command name. Now go to Preferences -> Key bindings - User. This opens the JSON config file in the `User` package where you can set your own setting. Add an entry like:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+t"], "command": "toggle_tabs" }
```

Comment: +1 for not only giving the answer, but showing how you got there in a simple way that expands one's knowledge of the API

Comment: It's worth noting that, at least in Sublime Text 3, the default command bound to `ctrl+shift+t` is `reopen_last_file`, which is very handy. You might want to use a different key binding if this is a useful feature for you.

Comment: Sir, you're awesome.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac OS X, you can go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts, then add a new key binding for the specific menu item.